# Entity Framework - lazy load through virtual keyword - detect circular references

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Entity Framework lazy loads Collections in the background if they are marked with a virtual keyword (for proxying) and lazy loading is enabled on context. So for example:

```
public class Entity()
{
    public virtual ICollection<OtherEntity> OtherEntities { get; set; }
}
```

EF will load OtherEntities even if the relevant method fetching it from the database doesn't have an Include for this entity.

Knowing that it causes issues with serialization and it loads tons of unnecessary data into created results overriding whats in the serializer, I started removing the virtual keywords and adding includes in relevant repositories but we still tend to pop into the dreaded circular reference issue once every while with Created results. Some entities might have tens of collections inside so its difficult to debug and it doesn't even throw an exception but just cycles between entities consuming more and more memory. I am forced to manually track down where it starts cycling. This is time consuming and horribly unfun. Any idea if there is a better way to localize the Collections causing issues with serialization?

We are using newtonsoft for serialization as with 99% of .net projects.

Answer (score -1):

First, you can disable lazy loading via the configuration and leave the `virtual` properties alone in the event you ever want to use lazy loading:

```
dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Second, lazy loading isn't the only problem with circular references - EF will hook up any tracked entities if the contents of their nav properties/collections are retrieved from the database separately (which is why you're experiencing the 'occasional' problem after removing all your `virtual` keywords.

You can configure one side of a circular reference to not serialize (e.g. `ScriptIgnoreAttribute`), but that will always prevent serialization (e.g. if you ignore `OtherEntity.Entity` so that you may serialize an `Entity` object graph without circular references, it would prevent you from including `OtherEntity.Entity` when serializing an `OtherEntity` object graph).

Another choice is to create a separate view model (or data transfer object) to control how your data is serialized.

Then there are serialization format specifications which avoid the problem altogether by only including referenced data if specifically requested (e.g. [OData](https://www.odata.org/documentation/) and [JSON-API](http://jsonapi.org)).  JSON-API also only includes each object once in the entire response.